# How to run an Inferno project?

Tags: typescript, infernojs

Hi I am trying to run this github project https://github.com/LemmyNet/lemmy-ui

How do I run it? I tried using npm start it says yarn not found.

Answer (score 0):

a

> example-package not found

Error means that a dependency is missing.
In this case, yarn. You can install yarn with

> npm i -g yarn

I encourage you to look into the npm help files and/or manual if you do not understand that command.

Take a look at the repo and see if there is a yarn.lock file. If there is,  you will probably be better off running the app with yarn, rather than npm. You may want to consult the yarn documentation.